# Do ActiveRecord locks have to occur inside a transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Do ActiveRecord locks only work when they are inside of a transaction? If I open up two rails consoles and find a record then call `lock!` on that record I can still access the record from the other console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#method-i-lock-21), `lock!` does not include a transaction. `with_lock` does, though, and should prevents you from writing to (but not reading from) the locked record.